# AWS EBS Volume - Python - Find all fields info as shown in AWS EC2 EBS Volume Console

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto, boto3

I'm trying to create a Python script to generate a `csv` format file against all the available AWS EBS volumes and showing all the field values as I see them in AWS EC2 EBS Volume Console.

```
[arun@Andrews-MBP-2 ~/aks/always-latest-ws-sunny/anisble] $ cat ~/aws-vol-info.py 
import boto3

#define the connection
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name="us-west-2")

volumes = ec2.volumes.all()

for vol in volumes:
    print "Created(" + str(vol.create_time) + "),VolumeState(" + str(vol.state) + "),VolumeID(" + str(vol.id) + "),VolumeSize(" + str(vol.size) + ") " + vol.type
[arun@Andrews-MBP-2 ~/aks/always-latest-ws-sunny/anisble] $
```

This script is giving me the following error message. Reason: The above script works if I don't use `vol.type` field. It didn't work as *volumes* variable never got that into it's value when it ran `ec2.volumes.all()`.

```
[arun@Andrews-MBP-2 ~/aks/always-latest-ws-sunny/anisble] $ python ~/aws-vol-info.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/arun/aws-vol-info.py", line 9, in <module>
    print "Created(" + str(vol.create_time) + "),VolumeState(" + str(vol.state) + "),VolumeID(" + str(vol.id) + "),VolumeSize(" + str(vol.size) + ") " + vol.type
AttributeError: 'ec2.Volume' object has no attribute 'type'
[arun@Andrews-MBP-2 ~/aks/always-latest-ws-sunny/anisble] $
```

What library/function should I use / change in the above script using which I can show all the fields or some more meaningful fields of an EBS volume (what I see in AWS EC2 EBS Volume console), see picture below for the available fields in AWS Console.

[image]

I found this other script (#2) online on [Github](https://github.com/riteshapatel/DevOps), which seems like it can print some more fields, but it's giving another error listed below. I successfully ran `python -m pip install --user aws` or `python -m pip install aws` or `pip install aws`, or ran the script (which included lines only after `#Import classes from aws package` [line](https://riteshpatel.silvrback.com/devops-with-boto-python-part-iv), inside the `aws` folder per his repository (after cloning it) but still getting the error.

```
import boto.ec2
class Volumes:
    def __init__(self):
        ''' Volumes Constructor '''

    def list_volumes(conn):
        ''' List Volumes '''
        # get all volumes
        vols = conn.get_all_volumes()

        # if volumes found
        if vols:
            #loop through volumes
            for v in vols:
                print 'Volume Id:', v.id
                print 'Volume Status:', v.status
                print 'Volume Size:', v.size
                print 'Zone:', v.zone
                print 'Volume Type:', v.type
                print 'Encrypted:', v.encrypted

                #print attachment set object
                attachmentData = v.attach_data
                print 'Instance Id:', attachmentData.instance_id
                print 'Attached Time:', attachmentData.attach_time
                print 'Device:', attachmentData.device
                print '**********************************'

#Import classes from aws package
from aws import Connection
from aws import EC2Instance
from aws import Volumes
#import aws

connInst = Connection()
conn = connInst.ec2Connection()

#instantiate Volumes and list volumes
volumeInst = Volumes()
volumeInst.list_volumes(conn)
```

Script# 2 error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/arun/aws-vol-info2.py", line 30, in <module>
    from aws import Connection
ImportError: cannot import name Connection
```

If I comment the lines in script# 2 which says `from aws ... ..` and just use/uncomment `import aws`, then I'm getting this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/arun/aws-vol-info2.py", line 35, in <module>
    connInst = Connection()
NameError: name 'Connection' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for `vol.volume_type`. You can see a full list of attributes in `ec2.Volume` here:
http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#volume

Comment: Seems close, I tried this `import boto3
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name="us-west-2")
volumes = ec2.volumes.all()

for vol in volumes:
    for inst_vol in ec2.Volume(vol.id):
        print "-- " + str(inst_vol.volume_type)` but it still errors out. Poking into it.

Comment: This worked: `volume = ec2.Volume('vol-b4e1fabc')
print volume.volume_type` but, I wonder, why it didn't work when I used 2 for loops above. First `for` loop will pass a valid volume ID `vol-xxxxx` to `ec2.Volume(<here>)` but it cried with this error: `for inst_vol in ec2.Volume(vol.id):
TypeError: 'ec2.Volume' object is not iterable`.
`

Comment: Because `ec2.Volume` is not a `list` but a class. You cannot iterate through it. The original print statement you had above will work now:

    `print "Created(" + str(vol.create_time) + "),VolumeState(" + str(vol.state) + "),VolumeID(" + str(vol.id) + "),VolumeSize(" + str(vol.size) + ") " + vol.volume_type`

Comment: Never mind, thanks it worked now. I don't have to use 2nd `for` loop. Still checking if that'll give me all the fields as per the AWS Console.

Answer (score 0):

This script can be enhanced to show more meaningful info but using the hint from *jpavs*, I came up with this script `~/aws-vol-info.py`:

```
import boto3

# Define the connection
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name="us-west-2")

# Find all volumes
volumes = ec2.volumes.all()

# Loop through all volumes and pass it to ec2.Volume('xxx')
for vol in volumes:
    iv = ec2.Volume(str(vol.id))
    print "Created(" + str(iv.create_time) + "),AZ(" + str(iv.availability_zone) + "),VolumeID(" + str(iv.volume_id) + "),VolumeType(" + str(iv.volume_type) + "),State(" + str(iv.state) + "),Size(" + str(iv.size) + "),IOPS(" + str(iv.iops) + "),IsEncrypted(" + str(iv.encrypted) + "),SnapshotID(" + str(iv.snapshot_id) + "),KMS_KEYID(" + str(iv.kms_key_id) + ")",

    # The following next 2 print statements variables apply only in my case.
    print ",InstanceID(" + str(iv.attachments[0]['InstanceId']) + "),InstanceVolumeState(" + str(iv.attachments[0]['State']) + "),DeleteOnTerminationProtection(" + str(iv.attachments[0]['DeleteOnTermination']) + "),Device(" + str(iv.attachments[0]['Device']) + ")",
    if iv.tags:
        print ",Name(" + str(iv.tags[0]['Name']) + "),Mirror(" + str(iv.tags[0]['mirror']) + "),Role(" + str(iv.tags[0]['role']) + "),Cluster(" + str(iv.tags[0]['cluster']) + "),Hostname(" + str(iv.tags[0]['hostname']) + "),Generation(" + str(iv.tags[0]['generation']) + "),Index(" + str(iv.tags[0]['index']) + ")"
    print ""
```

**Ran:** `python ~/aws-vol-info.py` and it gave me a CSV format values for all the fields mentioned in the python script. Few (2-3) AWS Console fields are missing as the library doesn't provide those, but whatever I can get from the above or if I dig into `iv.attachments[0]['<somekey>']` or `iv.tags[0]['<somekey>']` would be sufficient for me at this time.

**PS**: `iv.attachments` and `iv.tags` both are List/dictionary type variables within the `iv` object, so you can enhance the script by showing what exactly you want to fetch from it. Thus, if you want the `InstanceID` then you can use this: `str(iv.attachments[0]['InstanceId'])` to print that.

For a even better version: Check the .python script here: [telegraf - exec plugin - aws ec2 ebs volumen info - metric parsing error, reason: [missing fields] or Errors encountered: [ invalid number]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42708348/telegraf-exec-plugin-aws-ec2-ebs-volumen-info-metric-parsing-error-reason)

Found this useful script here as well: http://www.n2ws.com/blog/ebs-report.html