# How to receive systemd status and docker container status in telegraph?

Tags: systemd, docker-container, telegraf, telegraf-plugins

I am trying to use telegraph to stream docker stats, to do so I am using docker input plugin as specified here - https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/inputs/docker

I am trying to send my output to a file. I notice that I am getting all docker_container data except docker_container_status as specified in their input plugin page. I am able to see

```
docker_container_mem
docker_container_cpu
docker_container_net
docker_container_blkio
```

but not

```
docker_container_status
```

I need the status of all containers for my work, any help is greatly appreciated.

Some information about my setup:

```
Telegraf version : 1.7.3
```

Also is there any way to monitor systemd services status using telegraph? I currently see that there is a feature requirement that is not yet merged - https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/issues/2109

UPDATE - 1:
docker container status is available only in version 1.8 which is not released yet.

So any suggestions on how to monitor systemd status using telegraf?

Comment: The plugin for systemd is almost ready, https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/pull/4532/files/3d92218f4aa723742a0e3ef2a6a9e48c9e974e22#diff-65ed954dbdf59dc6a26b68cec53ce730

would you rather prefer an alternate solution until its ready to use?

Comment: @SufiyanGhori Thanks for the info, if I have to have an alternate solution what would it be?

Comment: you can use `exec` input plugin to fetch output of `systemctl` command

Comment: oh cool, let me quickly try that and get back. Thanks

Comment: an example and some tips: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42708348/telegraf-exec-plugin-aws-ec2-ebs-volumen-info-metric-parsing-error-reason/42709771#42709771

Answer (score 0):

The current version of Telgraf is 1.9x which includes the `docker_container_status` metrics.

[Plugin ID: docker](https://docs.influxdata.com/telegraf/v1.9/plugins/inputs/#docker)